# INSERT mySQL record if conditions are met

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I'm creating a highscore table for a game using PHP and a MySQL db

I've got it so that it inserts your score, and then tells you your position, but to prevent spamming the board with the same person I want it to check the following,

```
if score from your IP exists and score > your_current_highscore
UPDATE score
```

This is pretty easy, what is making it hard is that instead of 'score' there's 2 variables, 'TIME' (how long it took to finish) and 'PERCENT' (how much of the game they completed).

I'm not sure how to structure the SQL STATEMENT, whether i need

```
if time OR percent > current
```

or;

```
if time AND percent > current
```

TIME would be the dominant SORT, with percent second

Can anyone uncomplicate this for me?

Comment: So getting through more of the game faster would result in a better ranking, and therefore update an existing record? And does the query need to insert if there's no match on IP address?

Comment: Yeah thats right. I can deal with the insert if it doesn't exist, it's just the updating part I can't get my head round because of the 2 variables

Comment: What if the player gets through more of the game, but takes longer?

Comment: The emphasis is on the time for speedrunning

Comment: What's the name of the table? What fields are on it?

Comment: table is leaderboards, fields are IP, time (INT field for minutes), percent, name. i think it only needs updating if the time is greater if I'm right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will update the record if

1. the new time is better and the percent is better or equal, or
2. the new time is the same but the percent completed is better:

   ```
   UPDATE leaderboards
   SET time=[player new time],
       percent=[player new percent]
   WHERE ip=[player IP]
       AND (
           /*new time is better than old time AND new percent is better than or equal to old percent*/
           time > [player new time]
               AND percent <=[player new percent] /*maybe you don't want this condition, see next proposal*/

           /*OR new time is equal to old time AND new percent is better than old percent */
           OR (
           time =[player new time] 
               AND percent < [player new percent])
       )
   ```

Alternately, this query will update record if

1. the new time is better (*regardless of change in percent*), or
2. the new time is the same but the percent completed is better:

   ```
   UPDATE leaderboards
   SET time=[player new time],
       percent=[player new percent]
   WHERE ip=[player IP]
       AND (
           /*new time is better than old time, regardless of change in percent*/
           time > [player new time]

           /*OR new time is equal to old time AND new percent is better than old percent */
           OR (
           time =[player new time] 
               AND percent < [player new percent])
       )
   ```

Comment: i was working on my own code to answer this but yours is much cleaner, thanks.

Comment: If you want a little more sophistication, add some range-based logic for what is considered an improvement, ie: `time * 1.05 > [player new time] AND percent * 1.10 < [player new percent]`, which would update the record if the time is within 5% of the last time (even if worse), but 10% better on the percent.

Answer (score 1):

Try (sort of a metalanguage for table names):

```
UPDATE score_table
SET    score = new_score
WHERE  score > your_current_highscore AND
       score in (SELECT score
                 FROM table_with_ips
                 WHERE ip = your_ip) AND
       user_id = your_user_id
```

If `score > your_current_highscore` is false, then just no entries will be updated.

Since you have two parameters (time and percentage) and first one is dominant, you can check score like this:

```
--- score > your_current_hightscore
+++ time > your_current_time OR
+++ (time = your_current_time AND percentage > your_current_percentage)
```

Comment: The problem is it's not a 'score', it's 2 variables instead- 'percent' and 'time'. 'time' is the primary